# p5.js mousePressed line animation

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In p5.js I'm trying to create an animation where the bottom point of the lines smoothly (5px per frame) move to the bottom left corner of the canvas when the mouse is pressed. I can get them to the point they need to get to with lines.align but they instantly move there instead of animating.

```js
    let lines = []

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(600, 400);
      for(let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
          lines[i] = new Line(random(600), 0, random(600), 400, random(149,212), random(89, 146), 1);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
      background(32, 44, 57);
      for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        lines[i].show();
      }
    }

    function mousePressed() {
      for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        lines[i].align();
      }
    }

    class Line {
      constructor(xStart, yStart, xFinish, yFinish, g, b, w) {
        this.xStart = xStart;
        this.yStart = yStart;
        this.xFinish = xFinish;
        this.yFinish = yFinish;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.w = w;
      }

      show() {
        stroke(242, this.g, this.b);
        strokeWeight(this.w);
        line(this.xStart, this.yStart, this.xFinish, this.yFinish);
      }

      align() {
        while (this.xFinish > 0) {
          this.xFinish = this.xFinish - 5;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is not executable; are there missing some libraries?

Comment: apart from the p5.js libraries i'm not sure?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a blocking `while` loop which is why visually you see a jump from the lines' start to end positions.

One option is to use a condition and increment the value in `draw()`:

```js
let lines = []

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(600, 400);
      for(let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
          lines[i] = new Line(random(600), 0, random(600), 400, random(149,212), random(89, 146), 1);
        }
    }

    function draw() {
      background(32, 44, 57);
      for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        lines[i].align();
        lines[i].show();
      }
    }

    class Line {
      constructor(xStart, yStart, xFinish, yFinish, g, b, w) {
        this.xStart = xStart;
        this.yStart = yStart;
        this.xFinish = xFinish;
        this.yFinish = yFinish;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.w = w;
      }

      show() {
        stroke(242, this.g, this.b);
        strokeWeight(this.w);
        line(this.xStart, this.yStart, this.xFinish, this.yFinish);
      }

      align() {
        if (this.xFinish > 0) {
          this.xFinish = this.xFinish - 5;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You might want to also check out [lerp()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerp) to interpolation between start and end positions.

Additionally, if you need more control over timing/easing/etc you can use something like [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/docs/TweenLite) to do the interpolation for you. 
(It is a good exercise though to get a hang of incrementing values/interpolating/tweening manually first through)